# How to add prototype in string object using javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I want to add prototype function in string object. I working with it but it is not uppercase the string value. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efEzN/)

```
String.prototype.myUcase=function()
{
 return this.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: You don't assign the return value of `myUcase` to a variable, you simply ignore it. `toUpperCase` doesn't modify the string itself, it returns a new string.

Comment: `fruits = fruits.myUcase()`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/efEzN/4/. I have updated your fiddle

Comment: Why need to assign function in fruits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript String is not mutable. So, when you do `this.toUpperCase()` it does not change the current string. Instead, it creates a new string with the uppercased letters in it.

If you want your example to work, you can do (as suggested by elclanrs in the comments)

```
fruits = fruits.myUcase();
```

Comment: But with Array prototype it is returning value. http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prototype_array

Comment: @amit Correct. That is because, javascript Arrays are basically objects and so they are mutable by default. `this[i]=this[i].toUpperCase();` this particular line, modifies each and every element. That is why you are able to see the result.